# Change year/date format in option value=""

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown that shows options as year 2014 and the following ten years. The code:

```
 <select name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date" class='details_card_expiry_year'>
<option value="">- Select Year -</option>
```

The script

```
            var min = new Date().getFullYear(),
            max = min + 10,
            select = document.getElementById('expiry_date');

            for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = i;
            opt.innerHTML = i;
            select.appendChild(opt);
            }
```

However I don't want the value to show the year as '2014' instead it must just be '14'. 
How is this done?

Comment: Use Substring() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
opt.innerHTML = i;
```

You can use

```
opt.innerHTML = String(i).slice(2);
```

Comment: I actually needed it by opt.value and it worked thanks.